# Как вернуть данные в начало кода, если аргументы взаимозависимы? Алгоритмы

Tags: python, алгоритм

Пишу на пайтоне
Никак не могу понять, как сделать так, чтобы dv изначально был посчитан за счет известного числа, а дальше вставлял по одному элементу массива g

```
g = 1
v = np.linspace(0, 10, num = 6)
dv = v * g
g = []
for i in range(6):
    i += 1
    g_sum = sum(dv[0:i])
    g.append(g_sum)
print(g, dv)
```

Comment: Два раза перечитал вопрос и ничего не понял. Вы можете уточнить что вы пытаетесь сделать и что хотите получить в итоге?

Comment: как сделать так, чтобы для каждого эллемента массива v был свой элемент массива из g? Например v[1] умножается на g[1], v[2] умножается на g[2], v[3] умножается на g[3], и так далее

Comment: @Daniyar Zilgarin0v Если человек не может внятно объяснить чего он хочет, то вряд-ли он понимает, чего он хочет.  Тем не менее, если надо перемножить два массива, то делается это вот так : v = np.linspace(0, 10, num = 6)
g=np.array([10,11,12,13,14,15])
ma=v*g   Результат:array([  0.,  22.,  48.,  78., 112., 150.])

Comment: @passant g расчитывается через dv, а dv через g

Comment: Значит у вас итеративный процесс. Ну делайте цикл. Главное, чтобы процесс сходился